# Dev-C++ giving error for Makefile.win and g++ stop

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors, dev-c++

(sorry for my bad English) why dev-c++ show me this error in makefile.win and how do I fix it?

[[image: Error when compiling a cpp program]]

Makefile.win:

````
```# Project: 1TermResult
   # Makefile created by Embarcadero Dev-C++ 6.3

   CPP      = g++.exe
   CC       = gcc.exe
   WINDRES  = windres.exe
   OBJ      = 1TermResult.o fns.o
   LINKOBJ  = 1TermResult.o fns.o
   LIBS     = -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Embarcadero/Dev-Cpp/TDM-GCC-64/lib" -       L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Embarcadero/Dev-Cpp/TDM-GCC-64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib" -static-libgcc
   INCS     = -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Embarcadero/Dev-Cpp/TDM-GCC-64/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Embarcadero/Dev-Cpp/TDM-GCC-64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Embarcadero/Dev-Cpp/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/include"
   CXXINCS  = -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Embarcadero/Dev-Cpp/TDM-GCC-64/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Embarcadero/Dev-Cpp/TDM-GCC-64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -       I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Embarcadero/Dev-Cpp/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-       mingw32/9.2.0/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Embarcadero/Dev-Cpp/TDM-GCC-       64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/include/c++"
   BIN      = 1TermResult.exe
   CXXFLAGS = $(CXXINCS) -ansi -fno-asm -traditional-cpp
   CFLAGS   = $(INCS) -ansi -fno-asm -traditional-cpp
   DEL      = C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Dev-Cpp\devcpp.exe INTERNAL_DEL

   .PHONY: all all-before all-after clean clean-custom

   all: all-before $(BIN) all-after

   clean: clean-custom
   ${DEL} $(OBJ) $(BIN)

   $(BIN): $(OBJ)
   $(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)

   1TermResult.o: 1TermResult.cpp
   $(CPP) -c 1TermResult.cpp -o 1TermResult.o $(CXXFLAGS)

   fns.o: fns.cpp
   $(CPP) -c fns.cpp -o fns.o $(CXXFLAGS)
````

Comment: Unless this is a very custom Make implementation, you are supposed to indent recipes  (eg the calls to `$CPP`) with a single tab character. Also, you did not show an error, just a red line.

Comment: We can not see "this error" - the error you are asking about.

Comment: Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a faster and more accurate answer.